# How can I get my Nvidia Quadro M600m to perform well on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, blender

I'd like to ask the community what performance I should be getting out of the video card Nvidia Quadro M600m when run under Ubuntu, and how to optimise it.

This videocard is rather low-end but it is the only Nvidia that fits into my Ubuntu box and Ubuntu supports it (it found proprietary drivers for it immediately alongside open source one).

I picked the driver that has the "tested" mark on it as it appears to be the most suitable driver Ubuntu found.

I'm using Blender and the video card performs rather poorly. In fact my quad core Intel processor does better job rendering than the video card which allegedly has 2GB of dedicated memory!

Don't get me wrong, I don't expect remarkable performance from a video card that cost £100 (approx. $160), but I did expect it to handle Blender well. I should be able to see those 2GB somewhere.

Would the videocard perform better using an alternative driver?

Comment: The card is still support by the newest Nvidia driver (460). Don't forget to disable Secure Boot or, even if correctly installed, you won't be using the proprietary drivers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto  I checked and secured boot is disabled. There are bunch of drivers available to pick from in "Additional Drivers". I selected the one marked as "tested". I'm just quite bumped out that I can't even tell that it is using the videocard. I should be able to see a difference when using Blender but I'm unfortunately better off using the processor for rendering. 2GB of dedicated video memory and I can't tell a difference.

Comment: Nvidia drivers come with Nvidia X Server Settings. Open it and make sure the High Performance / Nvidia profile is selected and reboot. "Auto" tends to not work and "Intel" selects the iGPU instead. Is this what you have been doing to toggle cards?

Comment: @ChanganAuto  Lovely ! Joke is on me because I completely missed that Nvidia X Server Settings were installed with the videocard ! Everything was set to its defaults so I set profile to "High Performance" and the videocard is now outperforming processor in Blender. Epic ! Thank you. I'll close this.

Answer (score 2):

@ChanganAuto brought to my attention that Nvidia X Server Settings get installed with new videocard in Ubuntu. After setting profile to "High Performance" I can tell the difference now.